# Xcode script build-step, copying frameworks fails

Tags: xcode, sh

```
CONTENTS_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}"
mkdir -p $CONTENTS_PATH/Frameworks
cp -R /Library/Frameworks/Cg.Framework $CONTENTS_PATH/Frameworks
cp -R /$OGRE_PATH/lib/$CONFIGURATION/Ogre.Framework $CONTENTS_PATH/Frameworks
```

I use this in an XCode 3.2.6 script (sh) build-phase to copy the framework into the app bundle. It works great the first time, but on subsequent builds I get permission/unlink/can't overwrite errors - it doesn't seem to like copying the framework on top of itself. Other copy operations do work as expected.

Is cp the wrong tool to be using or is there something else I should be doing?

**Errors:**

> cp: unlink:
>   build/Release/Mac1.7to1.8Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/Cg.Framework/Cg:
>   Permission denied
>
> cp:
>   build/Release/Mac1.7to1.8Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/Cg.Framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/cg.h:
>   Permission denied
>
> cp:
>   build/Release/Mac1.7to1.8Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/Cg.Framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/cgGL.h:
>   Permission denied
>
> cp:
>   build/Release/Mac1.7to1.8Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/Cg.Framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Info.plist:
>   Permission denied
>
> cp: cannot overwrite directory
>   build/Release/Mac1.7to1.8Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/Ogre.Framework/Headers
>   with non-directory //usr/local/Ogre.Framework/Headers

Comment: You shouldn't normally have to script copying a framework into a project.  What are you trying to achieve, and for what platform?

Comment: Can you post the actual errors?

Comment: @Jim why not? Some of these are frameworks I built myself (obviously not Cg, that's one example only)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same issue.  What worked for me was to manually delete the build folder.  Tried cleaning the build folder from Xcode (hold option while in the Product menu), but it wouldn't let me because it said I didn't have the right file permissions.  Manually deleting the folder in Finder fixed the problem.